# Estou tentando testar um jogo mas toda vez que tento dar run aparece "invalid syntax"

Tags: python

```
import pygame

def main():
    #variaveix
    pygame.init()
    tela = pygame.display.set_mode([300, 300])
    pygame.display.set_caption('THE GAME')
    relogio = pygame.time.Clock()
    branco = (255,255,255)
    azul = (0,255,255)
    verde = (0,255,0)
    sup = pygame.Surface((200,200))
    sup.fill(azul)

    sup2 = pygame.Surface((100,100))
    sup2.fill(verde)

    sair=False

    while sair !=True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sair = True
            if event.type == pugame.MOUSEMOTION
                sup2 =sup2.move(10, 10)

        relogio.tick(27)
        tela.fill(branco)
        tela.blit(sup,[50,50])
        tela.blit(sup2,[70,70])
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()   

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Essa linha:

```
if event.type == pugame.MOUSEMOTION
```

Era para ser assim:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
```

Ou seja, você esqueceu do dois-pontos (`:`) e escreveu `pugame` ao invés de `pygame`.

Comment: agr aparece line 25, in main
    sup2 =sup2.move(10, 10)
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'move'

Comment: @KeddyHecky Isso já é um erro diferente do que está na pergunta. Você estava perguntando por um erro de sintaxe e esse já foi resolvido. Quanto a esse seu novo erro, realmente, o [objeto `Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) não tem o método `move`, afinal de contas, uma área de desenho representa uma matriz de pixels onde desenhos são feitos, não faz sentido movê-la a algum lugar. Pode fazer sentido redesenhar-se pixels em posições diferentes ou mudar os números que você usa no `blit`, mas mover o próprio surface não faz sentido.

Comment: realmente._.  vlw

Comment: @KeddyHecky essa resposta foi a solução para o problema da pergunta? Se sim, marque-a como a resposta aceita